# how to prevent an hour in the past with KeyboardDateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I try to block the entry of time in the pass. I can prevent the date but not the time. have you got an idea to block the time also please.

```js
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
    <KeyboardDateTimePicker
        variant="inline"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        required
        label="send date and time"
        value={form.start}
        onChange={this.handleStartAtChange}
        onError={console.log}
        format="L LT"
        {...startKeyboardDateTimePickerProps}
        disabled={form.status === 'paused'}
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

```
let startKeyboardDateTimePickerProps = {}
if (isNew) {
    startKeyboardDateTimePickerProps.disablePast = true
}
```

Comment: One idea would be to validate it on your handleStartAtChange function. using moment isBefore, etc. In the error you could show the right note for the user. is that a good solution for you? or are you only looking for something that would disable the selection of those hourse in the selection view?

Comment: @urirot yes i'm only looking for something that would disable the selection of those hourse in the selection view

Comment: looks like there is already a github issue open for this. 
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1813.
In this case, I would either look for another library, or implement a solution in this one, or just use the idea I previously suggested.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't help me much